# Paypal pay upon invoice without payment wall

Tags: paypal

Is there a way to send the user to paypals "pay upon invoice"-page without using the iframe payment wall? I need to implement paying by invoice without using the iframe.

Comment: Are you referring to the PayPal Plus feature provided for German merchants?

Comment: Yes. I didn't know it's only available in Germany.